# Can I rename GORM's "version" field? (Grails 2.2 + GORM MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, optimistic-locking

I've got a domain object that already has a property called `versions`, so I'd like to give a different name to the built-in `version` property (used in GORM for optimistic locking).  For instance, I'd like to call it `updateCount` instead.

Note that I **do want the semantics of optimistic locking**; I just want to give the field another name.  Here's what I've naively tried (and it didn't work):

```
class Item {
    ObjectId id
    static hasMany = [versions: ItemVersion]
    static mapping = {
        table 'item'
        version column: 'updateCount'  //  <-- This was my attempt
    }
}
```

I would definitely appreciate any help in...

1. Determining whether this is possible, and
2. If so, making it work :-)

Thanks!

Comment: version column : 'updateCount' worked for me - Grails 2.4.4

Answer (score 4):

First thing first. MongoDB (NoSQL) deals with [Documents and Collections instead of Table and rows](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/).

Being said that, the domain class should look like:

```
class Item {
    ObjectId id
    String itemName

    static hasMany = [versions: ItemVersion]
    static mapping = {
        //Collection in Mongodb is to Table in relational world
        collection 'item'

        //attr in Mongodb is to column in relational world
        itemName attr: 'item_name'

        //After spending some time investigating it was found that
        //attr for version does not make any difference
        //The below would not work for implicit GORM variable "version"
        //default attribute name is the variable name.
        //version attr: 'updateCount' 

    }
}
```

In case you want to configure default property across the domains to switch on/off the versioning then have a look at [Global Mapping Configuration](http://springsource.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/2.%20Getting%20Started.html).

Comment: Thanks! I'm definitely aware of the difference between MongoDB and SQL databases :-)  I just hadn't managed to find http://springsource.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongo -- exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Having now tried the suggestion, I'm afraid to say it doesn't work.  @dmahapatro, can you confirm this actually works for you?

Comment: @Bosh Looking into it, I does not work for me either. Can you also test if it works for an existing attribute with name as `updateCount` in the collection.

Comment: @Bosh Looks like it is not applicable for version, but works great for other attributes like (String itemName) with mapping as `itemName attr: item_name`. Still investigating. Will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I have the same experience (can rename my *own* attributes, but not the built-in `version` -- which of course is my goal.)  Thanks for confirming that you're seeing the same behavior :-)

Comment: @Bosh Why do you need to rename `version`? If I am not wrong the `hasMany` relations says `versions`, right? I feasible, you can rename it to `itemVersions` (being specific) as well.

Comment: I don't *need* to rename it.  I wanted to -- and so I wanted to know if it was possible. "No" is an acceptable answer :-)